# How to subtract these two time series objects?

Tags: r

I have one time series object that looks as follows (sorry, I don't know how to format it any more nicely):

> Jan          Feb          Mar          Apr          May          Jun
> Jul          Aug          Sep
>
> 2010  0.051495184  0.012516017
> 0.029767280  0.046781229  0.041615717  0.002205329  0.056919026 -0.026339813  0.078932572 ...

It contains data from 2010m01 - 2014m12
And one that looks like this:

> Time Series: Start = 673  End = 732  Frequency = 1
>
> [1] 0.01241940
> 0.01238126 0.01234626 0.01227542 ...

They have the same number of observations. However, when I try to subract them I get the error:

```
Error in .cbind.ts(list(e1, e2), c(deparse(substitute(e1))[1L], deparse(substitute(e2))[1L]),  : 
  not all series have the same frequency
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to subtract the two?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

`str()` gives:

> Time-Series [1:60] from 2010 to 2015: 0.0515 0.0125 0.0298 0.0468
> 0.0416 ...

and

> Time-Series [1:60] from 673 to 732: 0.0124 0.0124 0.0123 0.0123
> 0.0122 ...

Comment: Can't really tell. First one may not even be a ts-object.  What does `str()` show about their structures?

Comment: @BondedDust RStudio shows that both are a ts-object.

Comment: If you do not post specifics we cannot help. The error says they do not have the same frequncy.

Comment: @BondedDust Okay, I've added the result of `str()` to the OP. Is there any other information that I could show?

Comment: The lengths are the same but the frequencies are different. You now need to look at `frequency()` applied to both..... as indicated by the error message.

Comment: @BondedDust Ah I see, thank you. The frequency of the first is 12 and of the second is 1. Do you know how I can make them the same frequency (lets say 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `frequency<-` function, but you can change the frequency of time-series objects using the `ts` function:

```
> x <- ts(1:10, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2)) 
> frequency(x) <- 12
Error in frequency(x) <- 12 : could not find function "frequency<-"
> y <- ts(x, frequency=12)
> frequency(y)
[1] 12
```